# .one() doesn't work like jquery.com suggests for first use

Tags: jquery

I've exhausted my researched on using .one() for my needs, and get it to work correctly per class selector instance, where it only shows once.  But on jQuery.com it states the following will work, where if clicked once, it will not run again if another element is clicked with that same class selector.  However, that doesn't work for me.  I have, and need, the same specific class selector on one page.

here is the code that jQuery.com gives as an example:

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
$("body").one("click", ".foo", function() {
alert("This displays once for the first .foo clicked in the body.");
});
```

the second one above doesn't seem to work as it says.  Does anyone know how to actually get this to work.  Where I can have .foo in several places, but the function only shows once, after one of the .foo is clicked.  And when another .foo is clicked, it won't run the function anymore?  Thank you much for any help/suggestions.

Comment: It works as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/Zdqpp/

Comment: The documentation is very very badly written and confusing here but it does what is said in alert : `alert("This displays once for the first .foo clicked in the body.");`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this comments, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). When read correctly (as [dystroy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777260/one-doesnt-work-like-jquery-com-suggests-for-first-use#comment18942984_13777260), it's not written great), the handler will only fire *once*, for the *first* element that matches the selector.

To have this fire no more than once ***per*** `.foo` element, you'll have to do this yourself (note we've switched from using `one()` to `on()`, and handle the rate limiting ourselves.

```
$("body").on("click", ".foo", function() {
    var self = $(this);

    if (!self.data('fired')) {
        self.data('fired', true);

        alert("This displays once for each .foo clicked in the body.");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zdqpp/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this one:

```
$(function(){
   $(".foo").one("click",function(event) {
      alert("This displays once for the first .foo clicked in the body.");
   });
});
```

this will hit `.foo` and `alert for one time` only. if you hit it again without reloading alert won't showup.

fiddle:  http://jsbin.com/eluquq/1/edit